# Handling maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, error-handling

I have created a program that uses recursion to solve simple mazes. In the event of a rather complex maze, I get a maximum recursion depth error. I have searched that error on this website and read threads, so I believe I have a general understanding of what is occurring.

Unlike the other threads I saw, I am not trying to increase the recursion limit. sys.setrecursionlimit() is not what I am looking for. I would like to be able handle the overflow, and instead of crashing have the program print a message (`print("Sorry but this maze solver was not able to finish analyzing the maze due to recursion limits)`) and close.

I am aware of using try and except to handle errors, but I'm not sure if I can incorporate that to handle a maximum recursion depth error.

Comment: Note that you can generally implement any recursive algorithm as a non-recursive algorithm using a queue data structure. That's one way to get around recursion limits.

Comment: Hi thank you for the information JME. I am required to use recursion for this assignment (it is a class problem)

Comment: @jme Any example of how to do this when you don't know how big the structure is (which is generally why most people reach for recursion)? For example, crawling a network of links on the web, or recursing through an API to get all its data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A maximum recursion depth error is just another exception; you can catch the [`RecursionError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError) (Python 3.5 or later):

```
try:
    solveMaze(maze)
except RecursionError as err:
    print('Sorry but this maze solver was not able to finish '
          'analyzing the maze: {}'.format(err.args[0]))
```

I've incorporated the error message attached to the runtime exception; for a recursion error that's `maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

If you need to support Python versions earlier than 3.5, you can catch the base class, [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError). If you are worried about catching runtime errors that are *not* recursion depth errors, you could introspect the `.args[0]` value:

```
try:
    solveMaze(maze)
except RuntimeError as err:
    if err.args[0] != 'maximum recursion depth exceeded':
        # different type of runtime error
        raise
    print('Sorry but this maze solver was not able to finish '
          'analyzing the maze: {}'.format(err.args[0]))
```

Demo of the options:

```
>>> def infinity(): return infinity()
... 
>>> try:
...     infinity()
... except RecursionError as err:
...     print('Oopsie: {}'.format(err.args[0]))
... 
Oopsie: maximum recursion depth exceeded
>>> def alter_dict_size():
...     dct = {'foo': 'bar'}
...     for key in dct:
...         del dct['foo']
... 
>>> try:
...     alter_dict_size()
... except RuntimeError as err:
...     print('Oopsie: {}'.format(err.args[0]))
... 
Oopsie: dictionary changed size during iteration
>>> try:
...     infinity()
... except RuntimeError as err:
...     if err.args[0] != 'maximum recursion depth exceeded':
...         raise
...     print('Oopsie: {}'.format(err.args[0]))
... 
Oopsie: maximum recursion depth exceeded
>>> try:
...     alter_dict_size()
... except RuntimeError as err:
...     if err.args[0] != 'maximum recursion depth exceeded':
...         raise
...     print('Oopsie: {}'.format(err.args[0]))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in alter_dict_size
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Altering a dictionary size also raises a `RuntimeError` exception, but testing the resulting exception message allows you to differentiate.